# From client code in a browser, Is there a way to keep certain data only for a single browser session? (lifetime same as session cookie)

Tags: cookies, browser, local-storage, session-cookies

Currently I'm keeping the client's token in the HttpOnly cookie but I'm thinking about using Authorization header instead of cookie to provide certificate to the server. because some architecture issues are making me unable to use cookie.

But I want the token always to be deleted after the browser window is closed. which means that the token is going to have same lifetime as the "session cookie".

So I thought I could use the cookie from the client code only to store the token or any indication. but as the cookie is usually for the server, and to being sent to the server, it makes me wonder whether it is a bad practice.

and I thought I may use "onunload" event callback to delete the the token in local storage. but what if the client's computer abruptly turns off?

So my question is, Is there any better way than using cookie? or Can I go in this manner(using cookie to store the token or related indication but not to be sent to the server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I thought I may use "onunload" event callback to delete the the token in local storage. but what if the client's computer abruptly turns off?

If this is sufficient for you, you can simply keep the token in a variable instead.

```
const token = 'some-token';
```

It'll be gone when the page is closed/reloaded/etc.

Alternatively, and what I think you really want, is sessionStorage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

> The read-only sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'some-token');
```

Comment: But the variables are reset just by refreshing. and sessionStorage is applied to every each tab independently, making the client have multiple tokens in a window.

If using cookie in this manner is a bad practice, should I rather be building a delicate system using sessionStorage to do what I want to do?

Comment: @JHLee I don't know what your specific requirements are, but if you need the exact behavior of the cookie without the potential security issues of sending your token over HTTP to the page origin, then you could use a cookie to store an encryption key for the data in LocalStorage.  It's a little off the rail, but that'd do exactly what you want, as any encrypted data without the key is useless.  And, the server may get the key but it won't have the data, so that's useless there too.  You could also keep part of the key only in local storage.  Or, double encrypt.  Lots of ways.

Comment: I have deeply considered and I concluded that using sessionStorage allowing multiple different tokens may have no problem. 

My authentication system is pretty much different from traditional ones and in my DB Schema, the tokens were like one-to-one relation. so I thought giving user multiple tokens may be problematic, though actually is not(maybe).

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and opinions!